# softlayer-client: unable to update VPN for User_Customer via REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, express, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am experimenting with the [softlayer-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/softlayer-client)  api wrapper  in my Node Express application. My goal is to update the VPN password of a User_Customer by calling the [updateVpnPassword](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/updateVpnPassword/) method on a specific user.

I can construct a call to achieve a VPN password update using `request`, but I'm not sure it's the best way to achieve the desired result.

Can the softlayer-client module be used to make an similar call to this:

```
function updateVpnPassword(req, res, next) {

    // Construct URL to update VPN
    myURL = 'https://' + <userIDAdmin> + ':' + <apiKeyAdmin> + '@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer/' + <softLayerID> + '/updateVpnPassword/' + <newPassword> + '.json';

    request.get({url: myURL}, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('error:', error); 
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
        console.log('body:', body); 
    });

    next();
}
```

My initial attempts have been to try variations on this:

```
function updateVpnPassword(req, res, next) {

    // Assuming var client = new SoftLayer();
    client
        .auth(<userIDAdmin>, <apiKeyAdmin>)
        .path('User_Customer', <softLayerID>,'updateVpnPassword')
        .parameters(<newPassword>)
        .put(function(err,result){

         console.log(result);
            if (err) {
                next(err); // Pass errors to Express.
            }
            else {  
                // update successful
            }
        });
    next();
}
```

But the console log gives an error response like
     `{ message: { error: 'Internal Error', code: 'SoftLayer_Exception_Public' } }`.

I expect a TRUE or FALSE response, to indicate the whether the update is successful.

A similar python client can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748290/softlayer-api-user-password-update) but I require an implementation in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with nodejs but I installed the package [softlayer-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/softlayer-node) and run your second code and it worked.

I also created the following script and I got TRUE

```
var username = 'set me';
var apikey = 'set me';
var userId = 1111111;

var SoftLayer = require('softlayer-node');
var client = new SoftLayer();

client
  .auth(username, apikey)
  .path('User_Custome', userId, 'updateVpnPassword')
  .parameters('P@ssword123')
  .put()
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

node command:

```
$ node updateVpnPassword.js
true
```

Did you tried by sending that request using curl or any other REST client like postman?

If you get the same error then I recommend you submit a ticket and provide information like the id of users you are trying to update the vpn password and the user with which you are sending the request.

Comment: your suggestions utilises promises and I wanted to use callbacks. However, your post inadvertently solved my issue. I was incorrectly using the username for the userId (softlayer unique id) value. A simple mistake on my part. I was also unsure how to pass the password parameter. I thought it had t be a Json object, and not just a string. In any case, you helped clear it up for me. Thanks!